# Initialization value for number in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I was going over the book "The AWK programming Language" and line 12 of the book gave this program:

```
$3 > 15 { emp = emp + 1 }
  END { print emp, "employees worked more than 15 hours" }
```

The input file is Test.txt:

```
NAME RATE HOURS

Beth 4.00 0
Dan 3.75 0
Kathy 4.00 10
Mark 5.00 20
Mary 5.50 22
Susie 4.25 18
```

The author says the result should be:

> 3 employees worked more than 15 hours

However, I am getting:

> 4 employees worked more than 15 hours

My questions are simply

1. is the default value for numbers in awk = 0 or 1?
2. Why is this same program not producing the same result?

I don't know if it makes any difference, I am running this on Mac.

Comment: Get rid of that book as it's very out of date and get Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins instead.

Comment: @EdMorton I found faulty examples in many books, including my own. :-)

Comment: @Arminius That example is probably perfectly correct for the ancient awk version that was around in the 1980s when that book was written but idk for sure...

Comment: Thanks guys, @EdMorton, I will look into that book. Not sure why I got a down vote but I am happy I got some really good help here though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding +0 and see the results then. which will make sure only digits are getting compared by your condition.

```
awk '$3+0 > 15 { emp = emp + 1 }
  END { print emp, "employees worked more than 15 hours" }' Input_file
3 employees worked more than 15 hours
```

Comment: `$3+0` or `int($3)`. Latter may be more descriptive for (obvious) beginner.

Comment: @JamesBrown but `int($3)` will cause the script to fail when `$3` is `1.5`, etc. To force a numeric comparison just use `$3+0` and then you don't have to worry about what your data values might be.

Answer (score 3):

The output is 4 because the first line (the header) also is more than 15 for the third field. You can try yourself by changing the code to:

```
$3 > 15 { emp = emp + 1; print $3 }
END { print emp, "employees worked more than 15 hours" }
```

This will output

```
HOURS
20
22
18
```

So what you want is skip the header line, which is easy in `awk`:

```
$3 > 15 && NR > 1 { emp = emp + 1 }
END { print emp, "employees worked more than 15 hours" }
```

`awk` can by tricky when it comes to numerical types and comparisons. To force a numeric handling, add 0 (like `$3 + 0`) as another user pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868358/5866580

Comment: IMHO, how about if any string comes after 1st line(I know OP didn't mention but still could take that scenario), so check my solution once to get rid of this thing please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868358/5866580

Comment: The (poorly formatted!) table at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Typing-and-Comparison really helps clarify what types of comparison occur given string, numeric, and numeric-string operands.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a ton! *That* was the link I did not find quick enough.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 -- good point. My intention was showing how to avoid the (often present) header lines, but I'll edit my question to refer to your answer.

Comment: I usually remove the header but as @RavinderSingh noted, I think it would make sense to go with his solution. Really appreciate it and it is good for my practice too.